# Jquery .children() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, captcha

I am trying to make a basic captcha module for jQuery. I have a decent start on it, but for some reason .children() doesn't seem to work. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pTbeW/
I currently have this:

```
$(this).children('.captchain-start').hide();
$(this).children('.captchain-show').show();
```

If I change it to

```
$('.captchain-start').hide();
$('.captchain-show').show();
```

it works perfectly. But this solution is less than ideal, because it wouldn't allow two instances of this captcha to be on the same page.  I suspect it has to do with the html being set by query, but I'm not sure how. I'm far from a javascript and jQuery expert, but this seemed like a relatively easy thing to do. What am I missing? Do I have tired eyes from looking at it so long? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$(this).nextAll()` instead of `$(this).children()` because the elements you want to hide and show are not children of the a element, but siblings.

See http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: I cannot comment on other answers, but @rich.okelly solution will not work, as children() and find() are both traversing into descendant elements, which `.captchain-start` and `.captchain-show` are not.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `'.captchain-*'` elements are not children, but are siblings. Try the following:

```
 $(this).nextAll('.captchain-start').hide();
 $(this).nextAll('.captchain-show').show();
```

Comment: to clarify, `.find` searches through ALL levels of descendants, while `.children` only searches immediate descendants (one level).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work. see http://jsfiddle.net/pTbeW/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
this
```

In your click event references the clicked element, which is the element with the class 'captchain-start'. So you do not have to scan for the children, you can use:

```
$(this)
```

for the actually clicked element or the element selector instead

instead.